# When integrating $x^2((3-x^3)^2)$ using $u$ substitution, why does $u$ have to be $x^3$ and not $3-x^3$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Title. I'm a high student self studying calculus and was wondering why the $U$ in the $U$ substitution in this case is $x^3$ and not $3-x^3$ since they both seem to work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Who told you it can't be $3-x^3$?

Comment: @Jinu Oh it can be $3-x^3$. In fact that's probably the first and the easiest substitution that comes to mind.

Comment: My friend told me that I was wrong and that I should've used -x^3, and I ran the problem on wolfram alpha and symbolab and thought that I was wrong. Guess I was right. Sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: You should look into MathJax syntax to format your questions. Also multiple $u$ substitutions can work for a given problem

Comment: Welcome to Math.ML. Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Answer (score 1):

Both the sustitutions will work here.But for simplicity take u=x^3 .You can take any one of them as u. By the way , what are the limits ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There are no limits are this is an indefinite integral ;)